# Jest Snapshot not being properly formatted with pretty format on updateSnapshot, eg. not having Object or Array added to snapshot

Tags: node.js, object, testing, jestjs, snapshot

My jest snapshots are failing with an error that shows the version passed in, which has been formatted with [pretty-format](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), doesn't match the snapshot which has not been formatted. [image]

I'm using jest 28.1.1.

When I run jest -updateSnapshot it updates them without the pretty format.

I tried updating the snapshots but they were coming through without the proper format.

Comment: Very relevant question. One remark, jest expects two dashes before the updateSnapshot argument. Can you please edit it?

Answer (score 6):

After hours of debugging I found the answer. My code base was using version 28.1.1 but globally I had jest version 29.3.1 running. They've since introduced a [breaking change](https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest29) in how they format the snapshots. When I would just jest -updateSnapshot it was using version 29 and updating them without using prettier. But then when I ran it from my package.json scripts it would run version 28 and they wouldn't match.

If I added this to my jest.config.js it worked.

```js
snapshotFormat: {
  escapeString: true,
  printBasicPrototype: true
}
```

But in the end I just updated the dependency to version 29.

Comment: Adding the code to jest.config.js before updating the snapshots (using --updateSnapshot) is very important as you make sure the update won't hide existing problems ("real" test fails). Only then you can update the snapshots and remove the code.